# MongoDB how to delete temporary collection after operations finish

Tags: mongodb

Sometimes I create a temporary collection to aggregate data from multiple collections into a single collection for reporting.  I need to drop this temporary collection shortly after a report is created to avoid filling up disk space with temporary collections from many report requests.

Currently I execute this from the application

```
db.dropCollection('tempCollection564e1f5a4abea9100523ade5');
```

but the results are not consistent each time it runs.  Sometimes the collection drops successfully, but other times the collection fails to drop with this error message:

**MongoError: exception: cannot perform operation: a background operation is currently running for collection databaseName.tempCollectionName**
**code: 12587**

What is a best practice for deleting temporary collections in MongoDB?  I currently name the collection with a UUID to avoid name collisions, and the collection is only used once before I attempt to destroy the temporary collection.

Is there a way to check if operations are in progress for a collection, and then drop the collection when the operations complete?

**note**: I do not believe this is an issue with javascript async code in the application.  I call the `dropCollection()` after the aggregation query completes.

Comment: I can successfully drop the collection if I insert a short timeout, but this feels hackish.

Comment: Do you know what operation is running on that collection? Seems kinda strange that something would be running on it after aggregation completes. Perhaps some indexing or something?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating this mongoose plugin, and it's been running great in production for over a year.  I create a temporary collection, then use `setTimeout()` to drop the collection 1 minute later.  1 minute is sufficient to query the collection, so the collection is no longer in use.

This creates collections with unique names, such as `z_tempCollection_595820e4ae61ecc89635f794`, so there is never a name collision.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var _ = require('lodash');
var util1 = require(global.appRootPath + '/lib/util1_lib.js');

function tempCollection(persistantSchema){
    persistantSchema.statics.resultIntoTempCollection = function (tempCollectionDataArray, options, callback) {
        var timestampSeconds = Math.round(Date.now() / 1000);
        var tmpCollectionName = 'z_tempCollection_' + (new mongoose.mongo.ObjectId().toString()) + '_' + timestampSeconds;
        var registeredModelName = 'tempModel' + tmpCollectionName;
        options = options || {};
        options.strict = _.isUndefined(options.strict) ? false : options.strict;
        options.schema = _.isUndefined(options.schema) ? {} : options.schema;
        var tmpSchema = new mongoose.Schema(options.schema, {strict: options.strict, collection: tmpCollectionName});
        tmpSchema.statics.removeTempCollection = function(tempModel){
            var maxRemovalAttempts = 3;
            delete mongoose.models[registeredModelName];
            delete mongoose.modelSchemas[registeredModelName];
            setTimeout(function(){
                mongoose.connection.db.dropCollection(tmpCollectionName, function (err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                            util1.saveError(err, 'server', null);
                    }
                });
            }, 60 * 1000);
        }
        // tempModel variable ref is overwritten on each subsequent run of resultIntoTempCollection
        var tempModel = mongoose.model(registeredModelName, tmpSchema);
        var promises = [];
        tempCollectionDataArray.forEach(function(doc){
            promises.push(new tempModel(doc).save());
        });
        return Promise.all(promises).then(function(){
            return tempModel;
        });
    }
}

module.exports = tempCollection;
```